# Блокировка файла на запись. Получения значения через ReEX

Tags: powershell

Всем привет!
Есть файл C:\Density.txt, в который периодически записываются четыре значения. Для обработки и дальнейшего анализа мне нужен только четвертое значени, "Density:".

Содержимое файла:

```
Solid density
Mass in the air:
           23.384 (1) g
Mass in liquid:
           23.383 (3) g
Solid volume:
               0.001 cm3

  Density:
          1111.586 g/cm3
           ==============
Solid density
Mass in the air:
           23.384 (1) g
Mass in liquid:
           23.383 (3) g
Solid volume:
               0.001 cm3

  Density:
          1112.586 g/cm3
           ==============
Solid density
Mass in the air:
           23.384 (1) g
Mass in liquid:
           23.383 (3) g
Solid volume:
               0.001 cm3

  Density:
          1113.586 g/cm3
           ==============
```

Нашел путь как получать четвертое значение Density:

```
$Text = Get-Content C:\Density.txt
($Text | Select-String -Pattern "[0-9\.].+?(?=( g \/ cm3))" -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

Но когда начинаю использовать блокировку файла через [System.io.File] получаю ошибку. От блокировки файла к сожалению отказаться не могу. Как правильно внедрить решение в код ниже?

```
 try {
 $text = [String[]]$FileModified = @() 

 $ScalesM = [System.io.File]::Open('C:\Density.txt', 'Open', 'ReadWrite', 'None') 
$OutFile = [System.io.File]::Open('C:\DensityOut.txt', 'append', 'Write', 'None')

$ScalesM2 = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($ScalesM)
      $text = $text + $ScalesM2.ReadToEnd()
           # $Text = Get-Content 'C:\Density.txt'
#Выдает ошибку:
            $text = ($text | Select-String -Pattern "[0-9\.].+?(?=( g\/cm3))" -AllMatches).Matches.Value

            $data = $enc.GetBytes($text) 
            $OutFile.write($data,0,$data.length) 


            $ScalesM.SetLength(0)
            $ScalesM.Close()
            $OutFile.Close()
            Wait-Event -Timeout 1
```

Answer (score 0):

если нельзя уйти от блокировки файла при чтении то это норм.

```
cls
$ScalesM = [System.io.File]::Open('C:\tmp\text.txt', 'Open', 'ReadWrite', 'None') 
$ScalesM2 = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($ScalesM)
$text = $ScalesM2.ReadToEnd()
$ScalesM.Close()
[regex]::matches($text, 'Density:\s*\n\s*(\d+\.?\d*)') | %{
    $_.Groups[1].value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Алексей спасибо!

Готовый вариант ниже. Надеюсь кому то будет полезен.

```
$TValue = ""
$enc    = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$NL     = [System.Environment]::NewLine

$ScalesM = [System.io.File]::Open('C:\temp\DensityNT.txt', 'Open', 'ReadWrite', 'None') 
$OutFile = [System.io.File]::Open('C:\temp\OutDensity.txt', 'append', 'Write', 'None')

$ScalesM2 = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($ScalesM)
$text = $ScalesM2.ReadToEnd()
$ScalesM.Close()
[regex]::matches($text, 'Density:\s*\n\s*(\d+\.?\d*)') | %{
   $TValue = $TValue +  $_.Groups[1].value + $NL
}

$data = $enc.GetBytes($TValue) 
$OutFile.write($data,0,$data.Length) 
$OutFile.Close()
```